# Get the spreadsheet row for a matched value

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm new to Google Apps Script & I'm trying to make a script for a spreadsheet where I can get the range for the matched value. But there's no function for the cell value like `.getRow()` or `.getRange()` or something like this since it's a string value. Here are my codes,

```
function getInfo() {
var ss1 = sheet1.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
var ss2 = sheet2.getSheetByName("Rates");
var getCountry = ss1.getRange(ss1.getLastRow(), 11).getValue();
var countryRange = ss2.getRange(2, 1, ss2.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
var getZone = 0;

for (var i = 0; i < countryRange.length; i++) {
    if (countryRange[i] == getCountry) {
        var getrow_cr = countryRange[i].getRow();    //.getRow() doesn't apply here for string value
        getZone = ss2.getRange(getrow_cr + 1, 2).getValue();
    }
}
Logger.log(getZone);
}
```

How can I get the row for the matched string so that I can get the cell value beside the matched cell value?

Comment: Could you provide more context? Do you just need to search for a string in a single row?

Comment: @kabiroberai, no. I get the string I need, but I need the range for where the string is matched.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your looping variable `i` starts at 0, which in your case is equivalent to Row 2. To help keep that clear, you could use a named variable to track the first row with data:

```
var firstrow = 2;
```

Then when you find a match, the spreadsheet row it's in is `i + firstrow`.

Updated code:

```
function getInfo() {
  var ss1 = sheet1.getSheetByName("Sheet1");
  var ss2 = sheet2.getSheetByName("Rates");
  var getCountry = ss1.getRange(ss1.getLastRow(), 11).getValue();
  var firstrow = 2;
  var countryRange = ss2.getRange(firstrow, 1, ss2.getLastRow(), 1).getValues();
  var getZone = 0;

  for (var i = 0; i < countryRange.length; i++) {
    if (countryRange[i][0] == getCountry) {
      var getrow_cr = i + firstrow;
      getZone = ss2.getRange(getrow_cr, 2).getValue();
      break;  // Found what we needed; exit loop
    }
  }
  Logger.log(getZone);
}
```

Since `countryRange` is a two-dimensional array with one element in each row, the correct way to reference the value in row `i` is `countryRange[i][0]`. If you instead just compare `countryRange[i]`, you are relying on the JavaScript interpreter to coerce the "row" into a String object.

Comment: Thanks. But I'm still getting 0.0 for `getZone` in my log.

Comment: Ok I debugged it, and `getZone` is receiving the correct value inside the loop but for some reason it's not showing in the log. Any idea why it's happening?

Comment: *DITTO* to u, at the same time I also found the exact `break` solution. Thanks mate! :)

Comment: The fact that the loop continues after a successful match should not matter here, since `getZone` is only touched if matched. However, a `break` will be more efficient.

Comment: @SinOscuras I was just about to say that too :p